# ¿Cómo puedo añadir un texto segun el numero de veces en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

La idea es que me añada según el número de veces pero me da error en innerHTML, haber si me pueden echar un cablecillo, sería añadir si tiene valor 2 dos nombres, pero sin tener que parsearlo a int
gracias !

```js
// Declaro la variable contador

let contador = 1;

const valor = document.querySelector('#span');
const botones = document.querySelectorAll('.boton');

botones.forEach(boton => {
boton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    const estilos = e.currentTarget.classList;

    if (estilos.contains('disminuir')) {
        if (contador > 1) {
            contador--;
        }
    }

    else if (estilos.contains('aumentar')) {
        contador++;
    }
    else {
        contador = 1;
    }

    valor.textContent = contador;
})
})

// Función para validar que se introduzcan más de 10 caracteres.
function validarTexto() {
var cadena = document.getElementById("texto").value;
if (cadena.length < 10) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
}
// Listener para el botón de "Introducir", que primero validará el texto y luego ejecutará su función, creando un p y un botón.
document.getElementById("btn3").addEventListener("click", function() {
if (validarTexto() == false) {
    alert("El nombre introducido contiene menos de 10 caracteres");
} else {
    var num_veces = document.getElementById("span").innerText;
    for (i = 0; i < num_veces; i++) {
        var parr = document.createElement("p");
        var txt = document.createElement("span");
        txt.textContent = document.getElementById("texto").value;
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", "./img/eliminar.png")
        document.getElementById("div4").appendChild(parr);
        parr.appendChild(txt);
        parr.appendChild(img);
        img.addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.childNodes[0]);
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.childNodes[0]);
        });
    }
}
});
```

```css
.container{
    display: block;
    height: 50vh;
    color:black;
    margin-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

span{
    font-size: 3em;
}
button{
    border-radius: 10px;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:10px;
}
input{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#nombre{
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
<title>Ejercicio-1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Ejercicio-1</h1>
    <br>
    <button id="btn1" class="boton disminuir"><</button>
    <span id="span" >1</span>
    <button id="btn2" class="boton aumentar">></button>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="texto" placeholder="Introduzca nombre" />
    <button id="btn3" class="boton introducir">Introducir</button>
</div>

<div id="div4"></div>
<script src="contador.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Es porque en esta linea tienes document.getElementById("span") y en el HTML no tienes ningun ID llamado span se llama valor

Comment: ops lo pase por alto gracias @Jorge Luis ahora si funciona ! un saludo

Comment: vale ahora lo que no me añade es el texto el numero de veces si son 2, 2 veces el texto y se pone a valor 1 haber si lo arreglo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquel `else` al presionar el botón siempre iba a declarar el valor del span en 1, he quitado el `else` y deje que el default 1 quedara al finalizar el script

```
else {
    contador = 1;
}
```

```js
// Declaro la variable contador

let contador = 1;

const valor = document.querySelector('#span');
const botones = document.querySelectorAll('.boton');

botones.forEach(boton => {
boton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    const estilos = e.currentTarget.classList;

    if (estilos.contains('disminuir')) {
        if (contador > 1) {
            contador--;
        }
    }

    else if (estilos.contains('aumentar')) {
        contador++;
    }
    //SE ELIMINO EL ESLE
    valor.textContent = contador;
})
})

// Función para validar que se introduzcan más de 10 caracteres.
function validarTexto() {
var cadena = document.getElementById("texto").value;
if (cadena.length < 10) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
}
// Listener para el botón de "Introducir", que primero validará el texto y luego ejecutará su función, creando un p y un botón.
document.getElementById("btn3").addEventListener("click", function() {
if (validarTexto() == false) {
    alert("El nombre introducido contiene menos de 10 caracteres");
} else {
    var num_veces = document.getElementById("span").innerText;
    alert(num_veces);
    for (i = 0; i < num_veces; i++) {
        var parr = document.createElement("p");
        var txt = document.createElement("span");
        txt.textContent = document.getElementById("texto").value;
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", "./img/eliminar.png")
        document.getElementById("div4").appendChild(parr);
        parr.appendChild(txt);
        parr.appendChild(img);
        img.addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.childNodes[0]);
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.childNodes[0]);
        });
        //UNA VEZ FINALIZADO QUEDA EN DEFAULT 1 (COMO EL ELSE ELIMINADO)
        document.querySelector('#span').textContent = 1;
    }
}
});
```

```css
.container{
    display: block;
    height: 50vh;
    color:black;
    margin-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

span{
    font-size: 3em;
}
button{
    border-radius: 10px;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:10px;
}
input{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#nombre{
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
<title>Ejercicio-1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Ejercicio-1</h1>
    <br>
    <button id="btn1" class="boton disminuir"><</button>
    <span id="span" >1</span>
    <button id="btn2" class="boton aumentar">></button>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="texto" placeholder="Introduzca nombre" />
    <button id="btn3" class="boton introducir">Introducir</button>
</div>

<div id="div4"></div>
<script src="contador.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```